# PYTHON, K-means, image color classification

Tags: python, k-means, image-segmentation

```
resultat=[]
t0 = time()
for n in range(0, len(images)):
    try : 
        misc.imread(join(path,images[n]))
        img=cv2.imread(join(path,images[n]))
        img= cv2.resize(img, pic_size)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float64) / 255  
        w, h, d = original_shape = tuple(img.shape)
        assert d == 3
        image_array = np.reshape(img, (w * h, d))
        image_array_sample = shuffle(image_array, random_state=0)[:1000]
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_colors, random_state=0).fit(image_array_sample)
        labels = kmeans.predict(image_array)
        result= recreate_image(kmeans.cluster_centers_, labels, w, h)
        resultat.append(np.ravel(result))

    except OSError:
        pass



from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

t0 = time()
Ks = [2,3,4,5,7,10,12,15,18,20,25,30,35,40,50,60,75]
km = [KMeans(n_clusters = i) for i in Ks]
score = [km[i].fit(resultat).score(resultat) for i in range(len(km))]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(Ks,np.abs(score))
plt.title('Elbow')
plt.savefig('resultat_kmeans.png')
plt.show()

print("Done in %.2fs" % (time()-t0))

MemoryError:
```

**Hello, please i don't know it does not work, it worked for 30 images but when i increased the number of images it crached. Thank you.
i really don't know how to proceed resolving this problem
it says that is memory error MemoryError Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 6 score = [km[i].fit(resultat).score(resultat) for i in range(len(km))] 
**

Comment: where does it crash?

Comment: Please provide more details. Where does it crashes? What error's are presented etc?

Comment: it says that is  memory error 
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: ----> 6 score = [km[i].fit(resultat).score(resultat) for i in range(len(km))]

Comment: how many images, what's the size of the images and how much RAM do you have?